# Can we update Product Position in Category with CSV in M2?

Tags: magento2, category, csv, sorting, sort-by-position

Can we update products position with csv in Category ? If yes than please share share any sample or example.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: found any answer ?

Comment: Nope, Alternatively I was create a product atribute and sort with date all products.

Comment: Try this logic, tell if it works
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/358817/magento2-4-2-how-to-add-product-to-a-given-position-in-given-category

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it with Magento Manager soft having ID and position columns in the file

Comment: what is  Magento Manager soft ?

Comment: please share with us